# Within a template distinguish between create and update form

Tags: django

If the CreateView and UpdateView are using the same template "model_form.html" then within the template how would I differentiate if I am creating or updating a form?

My generic view is as follows

```
class AuthorCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = AuthorForm
    model = Author


class AuthorUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = AuthorForm
    model = Author
```

AuthorForm is as follows

```
class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')
```

My template is as follows

```
<form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td>{{ form.first_name.errors }}{{ form.first_name }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td>{{ form.last_name.errors }} {{ form.last_name }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {% if form.isNew %}
                <input type="submit" value="Update Author" />
            {% else %}
                <input type="submit" value="Add Author" />
            {% endif %}
        </form>
```

In my template I would like to differentiate between create and update view?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In an update view, there'll be a `form.instance`, and `form.instance.pk` will not be None. In a create view, there may or may not be `form.instance`, but even if there is `form.instance.pk` will be None.

Answer (score 31):

### From docs:

> **[CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview)**
>
> *object*
>
> When using CreateView you have access to self.object, which is the object being created. If the object hasn’t been created yet, the **value will be None**.

> **[UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)**
>
> *object*
>
> When using UpdateView you have access to self.object, which is the object being updated.

### Solution:

```
{% if object %}
    <input type="submit" value="Update Author" />
{% else %}
    <input type="submit" value="Add Author" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround, is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

add this function in your both CreateView and UpdateView class:

```
# For Create
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['naming'] = 'Create'
        context = super(CLASSNAME, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

# For Update
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['naming'] = 'Update'
        context = super(CLASSNAME, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

then reference those in your template with {{ naming }}

example

```
<button type="submit">{{ naming }}</button>
```

Comment: Very elegant to use one template for create/update.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is to use template `yesno` filter as

```
{{ object|yesno:'Update Author,Create Author' }}
```

or *in your case as the author is same word in both so*

```
{{ object|yesno:'Update,Create' }} Author
```

*`object` becomes **yes** if only there is an object instance and that would be the `update view` while it becomes **no** in `create view`.*